# How to create Custom Module in DNN 7.3.3?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-6

Can anyone help to make custom module in visual studio for DNN Software.

Or any reference.

I am using VS-2013 and DotNetNuke 7 C#.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of module do you want to make?

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new - you should also consider creating Apps using 2sxc, instead of classic WebForms Modules. It's a much simpler, more advanced setup but can do basically everything a module can, just with automatic data handling/versioning, image processing, view management and more.